# Заинтересовала реализация событийно-ориентированной архитектуры приложения. Где можно найти подробное описание и примеры?

Tags: java, c++, архитектура

*Я новичок, прошу не плеваться, если я что-то не правильно понял или написал.*

Заинтересовала событийно-ориентированная архитектура. Где взаимодействие объектов построено на таких паттернах как:

- Наблюдатель (англ. Observer)
- Издатель-подписчик (англ. publisher-subscriber или англ. pub/sub)
- Посредник (англ. Mediator)

То есть **не** только внешний интерфейс реагирует на события, а все(или почти все) объекты взаимодействуют друг с другом с помощью событий(сообщений). А именно действуют через посредника, тем самым обеспечивая не привязанность объектов друг другу. 
Я так понял есть очень разные реализации данного подхода. Читал про всякие шины событий и т.д.

**Есть ли** подробные описания и примеры подобных архитектур приложений, а то вменяемого кроме описания паттернов ничего не нашел. Информации не так много по сравнению к тем же MVC(слоистой архитектуры). И соответсвенно хотелось бы понять **какие минусы** у данного подхода и почему его не используют и т.д.
**Был ли** у вас опыт построения подобных архитектур, и какие выводы вы сделали?

Надеюсь понятно описал.
Заранее спасибо за ответы:)
*Извиняюсь за теги, они для привлечения внимания, у тега "Архитектура приложений" слишком мало слушателей*

Comment: почитайте о smalltalk и Qt.

Comment: Этот подход широко используют: практически все приложения с GUI основаны на событийной системе. Недостатки - сложно понять ход выполнения, потому что события могут возникать где угодно в произвольный момент времени.

Comment: Что из этого вы уже прочитали и усвоили? https://www.google.at/search?client=opera&q=событийно-ориентированная+архитектура&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Comment: @andreycha
Там в основном идет описание про внешний внешнее взаимодействие с пользователем идет речь. Хотелось бы примеры архитектур, где внутреннее общение объектов происходит с помощью событий(сообщений).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Вот именно GUI у них и сделано на событ. сис. Хотелось бы примеры архитектур, где именно внутреннее общение объектов приложения происходит с помощью событий(сообщений).

Comment: Можно почитать про архитектуру Netty. Есть у неё работа с событиями сокетов. Можно почитать про слушатели событий в JavaEE. А вообще, во всех ситуациях применять один и тот же подход/инструмент не стоит.

Answer (score 0):

В качестве примера подобной системы применительно для GUI и C++ можно привести [Qt](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt).

Comment: Вот именно GUI обычно и сделано на событ. сис. и в основном это взаимодействие с пользователем. Хотелось бы примеры архитектур, где именно внутреннее общение объектов приложения происходит с помощью событий(сообщений).